# Blurry text while animating the rotation CSS

Tags: css

I have a problem with my UI.

The text becomes blurry ***DURING***  the rotationY on :hover.
It starts out ok, the text is very sharp but when I hover, the text becomes blurry DURING the rotationY. Once the transition of the rotation is done, the text becomes sharp again.

Parent Component:

```
<style scoped>
.carousel {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    padding-top: 35vh;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: 800px;
}
</style>
```

Child Component:

```
.carouselSlots {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: blue solid 1px;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

.carouselSlots:hover {
    transform: scaleX(1.5) scaleY(1.5) rotateY( 180deg ) ;
}
```

How do you eliminate the blurriness DURING the transition?

I've tried a solution that entails blurry text for the rotation, but I guess they don't have animation/transition and only support a static rotation of the HTML element.